# How to programmatically create a sale order line (Odoo 13)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a sales record

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [{
         
            'partner_id': 10,
            'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
```

I need to be able to create 'order_line' programaticaly based on a number from a variable. For example `if variable = 3`

```
  models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [{

         
            'partner_id': 10,
            'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
            'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
            'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
```

I followed the exact steps from here, https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/programmatically-create-a-sale-order-line-99981. But I keep getting errors as it seems Odoo has changed quite a bit since 2016. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: 2 things. The dictionary must have unique keys.  Use a for-loop to execute the same command multiple times. Also what is the error?

Comment: In how to write/create one2many entries Odoo hasn't changed since a lot of years. Just for information ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you forgot the closing bracket when you provide the value of the order line, and when you write `order_line` three times, it is equivalent to provide only the last value.

If you need to create three lines, you need to pass three tuples in a list using the [special commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/fa4f36bb631e82bc139e76461cf3ac016d9e88b2/odoo/models.py#L3440).

The following example will create a sale order with three identical lines:

```py
models.execute_kw(DB, uid, PASSWORD, 'sale.order', 'create', [{

            'partner_id': 10,
            'order_line': [(0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
                           (0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2}),
                           (0, 0, {'product_id':1,'product_uom_qty':2})
                          ]
            }])
```